# query fb group based on user online activity

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I am new to this group.

I have explored two fql queries on this group.

`SELECT uid FROM group_member WHERE gid = <group_id>`

```
`SELECT uid, name, pic_square FROM user 
 WHERE uid IN ( 
              SELECT uid FROM group_member WHERE gid = <group_id> limit 500 offset %d 
 )`
```

It fails when the total rows exceed 5000 (i am guessing so because I never got a result more than 4500 on groups that has more than 10000 members). I did not see a relevant table or field that is linked with group_member. Is there any way to narrow down the query by getting a list of users who have posted on group in the past 7 days?

The above queries lists all group members and I want to list only those who are active on the group in the past 7 days.

Please help.

Comment: What mean active? Posting, commenting, liking...?

Comment: Yes... any activity, liking posting, commenting, sharing any post of that particular group

Comment: Appreciate some help here. Thanks

Comment: Is there no solution?